# Unable to edit Page layouts

Tags: page-layout, error, gack

I encountered this problem while trying to edit the page layout of a custom object. Following is the error page...

[image: Error]

What may be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to open a case with SF support?

Comment: @mast0r I didn't because it's not in my hands. I thought I should share this because it might be a known issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened a SF Support Ticket and their response was that they were aware of the issue.

To fix the problem, please clear your browser's cache.

Comment: I didn't clear cache, but used a different browser and it worked! This might be an answer so I accepted. Any explanation for this solution?

Comment: @MnZ Could you please provide any info about working/non-working browswer? I am just curious.

Comment: Sure @mast0r. I usually work in chrome. I got this error while working in chrome. Didn't get this error with Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue today. The page layout in question was referencing a custom button calling a Flow, which had been deleted in the morning. 
I believe checking for any item deleted recently and related to the Object is a good start for anyone getting that error.